How to get MySQL LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE to work with JMeter?
I have JMeter 5.6 and MySQL 8.0.36. I have LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE working from Workbench 8.0 against a MySQL 8.0 server, but I cannot get this working in JMeter from the same server where it works in Workbench.
I have the mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar file in the JMeter\lib folder and also tried mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar (couldn't find a 8.0.36 version if that matters) and I still get "Loading local data is disabled; this must be enabled on both the client and server sides".
I know the server side setup is OK because this works with WorkBench and in WorkBench Edit Connections under Connect > Other tab I have OPT_LOCAL_INFILE=1.
I've tried different versions of the JMeter JDBC Connection string with OPT_LOCAL_INFILE=1 or local_infile=1 and it still doesn't work. Has anyone else gotten this to work?
FWIW - This all works with MySQL 5.7 server in JMeter using mysql-connector-java-6.0.3-bin.jar file. Do I just have the wrong jar file or am I missing a setting somewhere?

Thanks. I had allowLoadLocalInfile=true in my connection string but added OPT_LOCAL_INFILE=1 thinking I needed that, because I needed it for Workbench to work. I shortened my Connection string to just "jdbc:mysql://10.84.100.226:3306/${__P(dbName,${testDbName})}?&allowLoadLocalInfile=true" and that worked.
